# What can be a quicker way to generate a matrix which has at least one element non zero in a row?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am trying to come up with a big matrix of the size 10000*10000 that should have data type as float and at-least one of the elements on its rows should be non zero.

I was using:

```
import numpy as np
list_going_in=np.random.rand(10000,10000)
```

but it takes more than a second to come up with the values, rendering it useless for my application.

I have also tried using
 `np.empty()`

but that returns all elements of a list as zeros and therefore can't be used in my case

can someone please suggest the possible way to do this in well under a second. I will prefer if it is a numpy array

Comment: How about `np.full((10000,10000), 1, dtype=float)` ?

Comment: How much time does it take for `np.empty((10000,10000))` or with some lower precision dtype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the following code:

```
np.full(1000,1000, dtype = float) # or any dimensions you want it will be quicker
```

Comment: thank you this is actually better it was what I did, can you up-vote my question ???

Answer (score 2):

Finding random numbers is an expensive operation. So just create a matrix of all ones

```
arr = np.ones((10000, 10000), dtype=float)
```